# Challenges like RSA factoring challenge

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, number-theory, lwe, ring-lwe

[RSA factoring challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge) is a famous one and is still not completely solved.

Are there similar challenges for

1. Discrete log over $\mathbb Z_p^*$?
2. Discrete log over Elliptic curves?
3. LWE?
4. LPN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Not that I am aware of.
2. See the [Certicom ECC challenge](https://www.certicom.com/content/certicom/en/the-certicom-ecc-challenge.html)
3. See the [Darmstadt LWE challenge](https://www.latticechallenge.org/lwe_challenge/challenge.php) (part of a larger set of lattice challenges)
4. Closest is probably the [decoding challenge](https://decodingchallenge.org/), though this is not generic LPN. If you like opening cans of worms, see also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/list.nist.gov/g/pqc-forum/c/KzmgtZ3qBME).

Comment: As to 1, I know no challenge for Discrete log over $\mathbb Z_p^*$ either. But it is possible to extend RFC 2409's [Oakley groups](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409#section-6) to create more, say by steps of 32 bits starting from the existing 768-bit one; and then any nothing-up-my-sleeves value in $[1,p)$ makes a good challenge for the DLP; e.g. $\lfloor2^{\lfloor\log_2 p\rfloor}\sqrt3\rfloor$.

Comment: Do you know if the Certicom challenge is "active"? It seems that Blackberry owns Certicom now and the most recent references I can find to the challenges are from around 2010 or so.